# replace duplicates while importing a csv to remote mysql server with mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, csv, batch-file, duplicates

I am importing a CSV to a remote Mysql DB thanks to Batch command / Mysqlimport:

```
call "C:\Program Files\mysql\bin\mysqlimport.exe" -h host -P 3306 -u user -ppassword --local --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" livefeed C:\macro_vip\csv\financial_feed.csv
```

Lets imagine I have the following csv

```
  Date      User  Amount
  16/3/2016 John  100
  16/3/2016 Juan  86
  16/3/2016 Mary  77
```

And import it with batch command above

I import it once.
15 minutes afterwards, my automatic batch import process imports same updated file again, which now looks like this:

```
    Date      User  Amount
    16/3/2016 John  100
    16/3/2016 Juan  86
    16/3/2016 Mary  77
    16/3/2016 Paul  344
    16/3/2016 Jane  22
```

As you see there are two only two new record, Paul - 344, and Jane-22
How can I import these 2 new records from CSV to Mysql and make sure never to have duplicates?
Shall I do this on the import side with Mysqli? I was more thinking this should be done on the Mysql side checking a unified index or something.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Do you have any unique key? Then try [--ignore](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_replace)

Comment: The table has more fields and includes an id autoincremented primary key. I could set up a unique key based on date, username and amount for instance but I still want any csv imported to update the amount deposited/played by customer on this specific date. When the date changes, it starts over. This csv is a table from customers playing on a gambling site, the win/ loss from players must be updated during the full day for reporting purposes.

Comment: So what's the problem? Define that unique key on (Date, User, Amount) and use --ignore. The doc says: "If you specify --ignore, input rows that duplicate an existing row on a unique key value are skipped." So the data will be imported except of duplicates. Or i get you wrong.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you are right, but I do not want these imports to be Ignored, but rather to UPDATE the existing ones based on the criteria that date, user remain the same but amount is updated with the one in new csv being imported ... Shall I give a more detailed example ?

Comment: I linked the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_replace) in my first comment. There is also a --replace option. But in that case the old row will be completely deleted. If that is no option for you then you will need an other solution with `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..` which is IMHO not possible with the *import* tool.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks Paul for your help. It seems that the --replace option might do the trick. Let me check this ! Have a great week end

Comment: BTW you should update your question. You wrote: "Avoid duplicates" and "How can I ONLY import these 2 new records".

Comment: Good way to handle this is to create a trigger which runs on inserts.